# GridView limiting number of items displayed

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, mobile-application

I have an arraylist of images that I want to display in a gridview, but I only want 12 of them to be displayed at a time, and then have one change images every few seconds, however I'm having trouble figuring out how to even limit the number of images displayed to 12. I'm using a custom adapter, extending baseAdapter. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What if you start to solve this by returning 12 in the `getCount` method of your custom `BaseAdapter`?

Comment: Right, thanks. I actually tried that before and was getting another error that I thought caused the problem (it turns out network issues were the actual cause of the problem.

In regards to how the grid view actually updates the grid, when I call notifyDataSetChanged(), does it redraw EVERY single one, or does it redraw only the one that's changed? 
The reason I'm asking is because I'm now able to have a random one change every time by using an arraylist of size 12 to hold them as a buffer, and randomly replace one of the values with a new value. However, I want to add an transition of

Comment: some sort, which would require that only the one changed be animated.

Comment: If you want to animate just the item changed, then you shouldn't update nor call `notifyDataSetChanged`, but create some sort of custom view (as the gridview item) that you will change and animate it self.

Comment: Wait, just to clarify, so let's say I created the custom view already. When I change the gridview item, it will update itself on the screen without me having to call notifydatasetchanged?